# Import function only in another file

Tags: python, import

So in my `file1.py`, I have something like:

```
def run():
   # Do something

print "Hi"
```

Now I want to use function `run()` in another file.

```
from file1.py import run
```

However, when I execute the other file it also prints `Hi`. How do I suppress this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add the `print "Hi"` in an `if __name__ == "__main__"` clause.

When python imports modules *it executes the code contained in them* in order to build the module namespace. If you run the module as the main script the `__name__` is going to get assigned to `__main__` and the code inside the `if` clause is going to get executed.

Since you're not running the script as the main script the `__name__` gets assigned to the modules `__name__` (in this case `file1`) and as a result this test will not succeed and the `print` statement is not going to get executed.

```
def run():
   # Do something

if __name__ == "__main__":
    print "Hi"
```

Answer (score 1):

You should include after the functions this:

## this runs the program

if **main** == "**name**":# before and after 'main' and 'name' there are two under_scores!
print "hi" etc...

Answer (score 0):

if you don't want Hi to be printed, simply delete from your file1.py

if you want Hi to be printed when run() is called, then indent it so that it belongs to the run() function.